# Add text with script output

Tags: shell, output

```
for (( x=1; $x<=300; x++ )); do ( ping world$x.runescape.com -n 20 | grep Minimum | grep -oP "(?<=Minimum = )[0-9]+(?=ms)" >> RuneScape_Ping_Output.txt ); done
```

What this does is ping world.runescape.com 20 times and looks for the minimum ping and stores it as its output. It will do it for world1.runescape.com all the way to world300.runescape.com as specified. The output is just a single number which the minimum ping value.

The problem I have is that I want to World number and the output as it stores. So when it's pinging world1.runescape.com instead of storing just the number `30` (30 is the ms) I want it to display `World1,30`. Then if it does world233.runescape.com for example it would show `World233,55`

Is there any way to do this? Because sometimes there is a World122 but no World123, so unless I have something labeling each ping, it will give incorrect results by putting World124 where World123 is if no value gets return for 123, so I need to title them to get a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You want to echo before each bit of output.

```
for (( x=1; $x<=300; x++ )); do 
    echo -n "world$x,"
    ping world$x.runescape.com -n 20 | grep Minimum | grep -oP "(?<=Minimum = )[0-9]+(?=ms)"
done > RuneScape_Ping_Output.txt
```

I've moved the redirect outside, on the assumption that you don't want to accumulate results, just get the latest set.

Comment: That works great. The reason I wanted the comma separating them is because when I open it with excel, can separate them by using the comma. The problem I see now when I run it is that the pings that don't return any value or can't find anything to output get jumbled. For example if a ping times out, it can't find the words "minimum" to trim and output. So is there a way to return a 0 for things it can't find an output for? Would one use an "if" or something?

Comment: Add `|| echo 0` to the grep line.

Comment: But if the ping fails all it will say is "Request timed out." So would adding that still do what I am trying to? If it isn't able to ping at all I want it to display 0 or whatever I pick ya know

Comment: `echo 0` is only run if the grep fails to find what it is looking for.

Comment: Should I add it at the very end of line 3?